# MongoDB Aggregation - Creating new arrays from a given array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, aggregation

i wish to create new arrays from a given array based on my aggregation results, the desired outcome from the following doc is to split the array into new arrays where the split point is the action "start"

```
{
    "_id" : "5f851b06b08ab4b1f916c14841d4bbba",
    "actions" : [
        {
            "action" : "start",
            "datetime" : 1525692527345.0
        },
        {
            "action" : "scrolled",
            "datetime" : 1525692545966.0
        },
        {
            "action" : "scrolled",
            "datetime" : 1525692545983.0
        },
        {
            "action" : "click",
            "datetime" : 1525692545999.0
        },
        {
            "action" : "start",
            "datetime" : 1525693343877.0
        },
        {
            "action" : "mousemove",
            "datetime" : 1525693351075.0
        },
        {
            "action" : "mousemove",
            "datetime" : 1525693351117.0
        },
        {
            "action" : "scrolled",
            "datetime" : 1525693351212.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "scrolled",
            "datetime": 1525693354026.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "scrolled",
            "datetime": 1525693354126.0
        }
    ]
}
```

so next i should have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id":      "5f851b06b08ab4b1f916c14841d4bbba",
    "session1": [
        {
            "action":   "start",
            "datetime": 1525692527345.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "scrolled",
            "datetime": 1525692545966.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "scrolled",
            "datetime": 1525692545983.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "click",
            "datetime": 1525692545999.0
        }
    ],
    "session2": [
        {
            "action":   "start",
            "datetime": 1525693343877.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "mousemove",
            "datetime": 1525693351075.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "mousemove",
            "datetime": 1525693351118.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "mousemove",
            "datetime": 1525693351119.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "mousemove",
            "datetime": 1525693351121.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "scrolled",
            "datetime": 1525693351212.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "scrolled",
            "datetime": 1525693354026.0
        },
        {
            "action":   "scrolled",
            "datetime": 1525693354126.0
        }
    ]
}
```

*the `session1`, `session2` field name can be anything it's just for the sake of showing the desired result.*

any ideas how to add this to my existing aggregation pipeline?

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "action" : {
                    "$exists" : true
                }, 
                "domain" : "domain.com"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$action"
        }, 
        { 
            "$sort" : {
                "action.datetime" : 1.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$id", 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }, 
                "actions" : {
                    "$addToSet" : {
                        "id" : "$id", 
                        "action" : "$action.action", 
                        "datetime" : "$action.datetime"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$actions"
        }, 
        { 
            "$sort" : {
                "actions.datetime" : 1.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$actions.id", 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }, 
                "actions" : {
                    "$push" : {
                        "action" : "$actions.action", 
                        "datetime" : "$actions.datetime"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "count" : {
                    "$gt" : 1.0
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: You've lost me. `"session1"` and `"session2"`, where are these coming from? Nothing in your code so is this the wrong code or you expecting someone to answer and do that for you? If you expect someone to do it then how are things meant to be selected to go into those arrays?

Comment: Just trying to help you here as every question you have posted here so far is gathering tumbleweeds and you are not exactly participating in responding to feedback, clarifying or really "sticking with those questions" which I really can't tell from here if you've solved those issues or moved on. In a lot of ways this looks like the "same question", and you really are not meant to "re-post" the same thing with new or "progress" variations each day. You'll get more out of this by essentially "working" the one question. Respond to people and don't just leave them hanging.

Comment: i have edited my question to be more focused